# What's the meaning of 0x80..00 in objc-weak.h(objc runtime souce code)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm studying objc runtime source code, and I can't understand what 0x80..00 is.
It comes from the comment in file objc-weak.h. The comment shows below:

```
// out_of_line_ness field overlaps with the low two bits of inline_referrers[1].
// inline_referrers[1] is a DisguisedPtr of a pointer-aligned address.
// The low two bits of a pointer-aligned DisguisedPtr will always be 0b00
// (disguised nil or 0x80..00) or 0b11 (any other address).
// Therefore out_of_line_ness == 0b10 is used to mark the out-of-line state.
```

Comment: i would think of 0xXXXX0b00 or 0xXXXX0b11 or 0xXXXX0b10 which can be shiftet to figure out what state they have and still being an address. address length may vary on systems thats why the dots `..`. Hope i am not wrong.

Comment: @OlSen the "0b" in 0b00 or 0b11 means binary-coded digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisguisedPtr` is defined in [obj-private.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-781/runtime/objc-private.h.auto.html) which says this:

```
// DisguisedPtr<T> acts like pointer type T*, except the 
// stored value is disguised to hide it from tools like `leaks`.
// nil is disguised as itself so zero-filled memory works as expected, 
// which means 0x80..00 is also disguised as itself but we don't care.
// Note that weak_entry_t knows about this encoding.
```

Comment: Today, I realize that the complement representation of 0(nil) and 0x80..00 are still 0 and 0x80..00. So, 0x80..00 is mentioned in the comments for this reason(0x80..00 is also disguised as itself). _OBJC_TAG_MASK is 0x80000000, but no relationship with the 0x80..00  in objc-weak comments. Just a coincidence,  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that _OBJC_TAG_MASK is not related. I removed that portion.